# add checkbox in select2 to dropdown list in yii2

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

here is code of dropdownlist.. but when I select multiple values it gives validation error "task must be string"

**how to save multiple values (array)?**

```
   <?php echo $form->field($model, 'task')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                            'data' => $companiesList,
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select company...','multiple' => true],
                            'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true,],
                        ]);?>
```

**how to give checkbox for each value in list?**

Comment: in model rules set `[['task'], 'safe']`  from `[['task'], 'string']`.

Comment: PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
quoted_printable_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: quoted_printable_encode comes from your wrong rule arr paste all rule arr here  to help more

Answer (score 0):

you have to save multiple values in many-to-many tabels ,

after changing the rules  to `[['task'], 'safe']` from Mr Skull answer , you have to get all data like this :

```
foreach ( $model->task as $single_task){

$task = new _many_to_many_model();
$task->side_1_id = single_task;
$task->side_2_id = $model->id;
$task->save();

}
```

after this comment :

all selected value should go in single column

you don't need to use many-to-many !
I use "-" as delimiter,

```
$all_taskes = "";
    foreach ( $model->task as $single_task){

    $all_taskes .= single_task."-";

    }

$model->task = all_taskes;
```

Comment: in controller after $model->save() , but it's important to where do you want to save multiple  data ? and let me know in single column or many-to-many ?

Comment: all selected value should go in single column

Comment: Okey , let see my next edit to answer and put in in your controller .. forget the many to many ...

Comment: check it out , and see part 2

Comment: error...... PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
quoted_printable_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Hey sir this error is not depent on this code could you please give me the link of this error ?

Comment: in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\ContentEncoder\NativeQpContentEncoder.php at line 95

Comment: Serach this error and increase you limit configuration in you php.ini

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162122/discussion-between-kiamoz-and-darsh).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there ,

```
       $model->save();
       foreach ($model->task as $cat) {
    
                    $m = new \common\models\_many_to_many_model();
                    $m->ads_id = $model->id; // change in to yorr base model ID and use it's put after $model->save
                    $m->category_id = $cat; // category_id is your many to many model filed id 
                    $m->save();
       }
```